# Is there any expiry time for blob URL when it is stored in indexed db of chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome-app, indexeddb, offline-caching, bloburls

I am converting a normal image/video Url into a blob Url ,after conversion i'm storing it in INDEXED DB of chrome browser. To run the assets(image/video) in offline mode I have made this conversion.

When i run my application for three days continuously without internet,the image/video is not coming. As i'm running my application(it is a chrome extension ) in chrome box I cant able to inspect and see the error.Is there any expiry time for blob Url.

I have seen for whether auto clear of data is happening in indexed db  or not, but for chrome extensions the indexed db will not get clear unless the user deleted it manually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can certainly delete the IndexedDB items manually. Simply store a date field with each of the objects you write. Check periodically the items and delete those that are too old.

Comment: thanks "woxxom" ..but my doubt is whether indexed DB will get clear automatically or is there any expiration time/validation time for blob Url.

Comment: Why would there be? It'll just stop accepting new data and emit an error when the app's size limit is reached.

Comment: before reaching size limitation, is there any factor for clearing the data in indexed DB except manually?Also, the data what I'm storing in indexed DB is "blob Url" so is there any time expiry for blob URL?

Comment: No such thing. Just an error is displayed when it's full. See the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your information @wOxxOm

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idbcache) module, it lets you set data in your indexedDB only for x mins. After which, data is cleared automatically.